# Executing SQL with " " from Python

Tags: python, sql, ms-access

I have trouble executing a SQL-statement from Python because of the " " in the selection. I think I've tried every combination, but can't figure it out. Can you please help me?

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\python33\salesdb.mdb")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
v_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT tblSeller.ID, tblSeller.Navn FROM tblResult INNER JOIN tblSeller ON tblResult.SellerID = tblSeller.ID WHERE (((tblSeller.Name)="Robert Smith" ))"
cursor.execute(v_sql)
```

The problem is the " around Robert Smith in the SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would *escape* the quotes or use a different quoting style. Single quotes would do here, for example.

Using single quotes:

```
v_sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT tblSeller.ID, tblSeller.Navn FROM tblResult INNER JOIN tblSeller ON tblResult.SellerID = tblSeller.ID WHERE (((tblSeller.Name)="Robert Smith" ))'
```

Using escaping:

```
v_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT tblSeller.ID, tblSeller.Navn FROM tblResult INNER JOIN tblSeller ON tblResult.SellerID = tblSeller.ID WHERE (((tblSeller.Name)=\"Robert Smith\" ))"
```

or you can use triple quotes (one of `'''` or `"""`); these allow for easy multi-line strings as newlines are allowed and included in the final string value:

```
v_sql = """
SELECT DISTINCT tblSeller.ID, tblSeller.Navn 
FROM tblResult INNER JOIN tblSeller ON tblResult.SellerID = tblSeller.ID
WHERE (((tblSeller.Name)=\"Robert Smith\" ))
"""
```

Comment: I'm really impressed! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try mixing with single quotes:

```
v_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT tblSeller.ID, tblSeller.Navn FROM tblResult INNER JOIN tblSeller ON tblResult.SellerID = tblSeller.ID WHERE (((tblSeller.Name)='Robert Smith' ))"
```

or

```
v_sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT tblSeller.ID, tblSeller.Navn FROM tblResult INNER JOIN tblSeller ON tblResult.SellerID = tblSeller.ID WHERE (((tblSeller.Name)="Robert Smith" ))'
```

In python strings can either be quoted with a doublequote `"` or a singlequote `'`. This is very usefull in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can create string using `'` or `"` as other says.

But in this case I would like to propose using PreparedStatement instead of simple query. Such PreparedStatement uses `?` in place of arguments and arguments are simply array:

```
v_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT tblSeller.ID, tblSeller.Navn FROM tblResult INNER JOIN tblSeller ON tblResult.SellerID = tblSeller.ID WHERE (((tblSeller.Name)=?))"
rs = c.execute(v_sql, ["Robert Smith", ])
```

PreparedStatements have many advantages: they are simpler to database engines to parse, and cache query plans, they are SQLInjection attacks safe etc.

Comment: WOW! Even an answer to something I wouldn't dream of existed. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to add the , after Robert Smith? Does it also take another argument?

Comment: Yes, it is "open" array, list or tuple `("Robert Smith", )` and you can add more elements. They can be of different types. For tuples with one element `,` is obligatory and I use it also for lists with one element.